# Simulate jQuery (or pure JavaScript) Keyboard Event On Clicking a Link

Tags: jquery, keyboard, simulation, keyboard-events

Well, and my query is I want to generate (simulate) a keyboard event using jQuery or pure Javascript while clicking on a Link. For eg. I've a hyperlink in my page and on clicking that link, I want to trigger the keyboard CTRL+F event.

Link

```
<a href="#" class="ctrlf">Generate CTRL+F</a>
```

Function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("a.ctrlf").click(function(e){
   //Some actions :O
   });
  });
```

What should I write inside the click function for a.ctrlf?

Is it weird or something? Please share your thoughts if you've the solution. Thanks in advance. Cheers..:)

Comment: You want the javascript code to trigger a browsers API? I'm pretty sure that this is impossible, and I'm VERY sure that it would be very risky. Would you like any page to be able to do stuff with your browser / other programs?

Comment: @KamilT It's like trigger a keyboard event using javascript. Say, I want that 'Find' feature (CTRL+F) just using my code. Is it possible?

Comment: Well, I don't think it's possible, it would be an enormous threat. Just imagine what would happen if you came to a pernicious page which would trigger keyboard events, like "bookmark this page", "save page" or "open new tab", for a thousand times. If you never bumped into page like taht, then it is more that probable that this kind of action is impossible ;)

Comment: Then it seems like we cannot invoke browser controls from inside the webpage..:(

Comment: Why do you need the code to be able to trigger search dialog box? I think that you are just trying to achieve something, which is not important and can be done in a more efficent way.

Comment: My intention was to show the Bookmarks dialog (CTRL+D) when the user clicks on a link. I guess, as you said, Unless the browser provides an API (BOM - browser object model), We can't achieve the same!

Answer (score 1):

If it is about bookmarks, as you said in your comment, this is a slippery issue. Some browsers, like IE, Mozilla and Opera, are able to add bookmark "from code". You can't do that in Chrome, I don't know what is it like in Safari. The code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#bookmarkme").click(function() {
    if (window.sidebar) { 
    // Firefox
        window.sidebar.addPanel(location.href,document.title,"");
    } 
    else if(window.external) {
    // Internet Explorer
    window.external.AddFavorite(location.href,document.title); 
    }
    else if(window.opera && window.print) { 
    // Opera
        this.title=document.title;
    }
});
```

Still, most users will preffer to add the page to bookmarks manually, on their own ;)

Comment: Yeah..Thanks for the answer. I already had the similar solution but didn't work with chrome & safari..:( That's the reason I had posted this question!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a.ctrlf").click(function(e){
       e.which = 6; // # Some key code value
       $("input").trigger(e);
   });
});
```

Or is that not what you meant?

Comment: No..It's like triggering a keyboard event using javascript. Say, I want that 'Find' feature (CTRL+F) just using my code. It seems like we cannot invoke browser controls from inside the webpage..!